# React Js Dropdown in some cases select all the options from dropdown instead of 1 option

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, dropdown

For below given Code while selecting the value from the dropdown all the values are getting selected and stored, but again this scenario does not occur evertime and not for all users also on Stage environment while checking I could not generate this scenario.
I have used Select tag from material-ui for Dropdown action.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import "../assets/css/Tabs.css";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
import "../assets/css/InsertRecordTab.css";
import axios from "axios";
import { ThreeDots } from "react-loader-spinner";
import useHttp from "../hooks/use-http";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import { FormControl, InputLabel, Select } from "@mui/material";

const InsertRecordTab = (props) => {
  const { sendRequest } = useHttp();
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(false);
  const [errorText, setErrorText] = useState(" ");
  const [isTouched, setIsTouched] = useState(false);
  const [state, setState] = useState([]);
  const [isInserted, setIsInserted] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [selectedValues, setSelectedValue] = useState("");
  const column = props.processColumns;
  const Base_Url = "http://localhost:8080/atlas";
  const userName = props.userName;
  const processId = props.processId;
  const Spinner = (
    <div className="spinner">
      <ThreeDots color="#00BFFF" />
    </div>
  );
  const colLength = column.length;
  useEffect(() => {
    const setStateData = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      setState([]);
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1500));
      setIsLoading(false);
    };
    setStateData();
  }, [processId]);
  const handleFocus = (event) => {
    if (event.target.value === "") {
      setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [event.target.name]: "Blank" }));
    }
  };
  const handleDropdown = (cname, event) => {
    setIsTouched(true);
    const selectedValue = event.target.value || "Blank";
    setSelectedValue(selectedValue);
    console.log(selectedValues);
    setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [cname]: selectedValue }));
  };
  const handleSetJsonFieldsValues = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const nameValue = value || "Blank";
    setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: nameValue }));
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.isProcessSelected === true) {
      setErrorMsg(false);
    }
  }, [column, props.isProcessSelected]);
  const handleChangeEvent = async (e) => {
    if (!state || state === "Blank") {
      setErrorMsg(true);
      setErrorText("Please enter valid data!");
      setIsTouched(false);
      return;
    }
    let newState = [];
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(state)) {
      value = value.toString().replace(/:/g, "~");
      newState.push({ [key]: value });
    }
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      await axios.post(`${Base_Url}/InsertDataProcessData`, {
        body: JSON.stringify({
          userName: userName,
          processId: processId,
          jsonObj: { newState },
          selectedProcessColumnName: Object.keys(column.data),
        }),
      });
      setIsLoading(false);
      setIsInserted(true);
      setErrorMsg(false);
    } catch (err) {
      setIsLoading(false);
      setIsInserted(false);
      setErrorMsg(true);
    }
    setState([]);
    const ProdActresponse = (responseData) => {
      console.log(responseData);
    };
    sendRequest(
      {
        url: "/ProcessDataActivities",
        body: {
          Activity_Name: "PRODUCTION ACTIVITY",
          comments: null,
          Current_ProcessID: processId,
          userName: userName,
        },
      },
      ProdActresponse
    );
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    props.isInserted(isInserted);
    setIsInserted(false);
  }, [isInserted, props]);
  const inputTouchHandler = () => {
    setIsTouched(true);
  };
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Helmet>
        <style>{"body{background-color: rgb(230, 233, 239);}"}</style>
      </Helmet>
      <div className="main-container">
        <form>
          <Card>
            <div>
              <h2
                className="box-title"
                style={{
                  marginTop: "20px",
                  marginLeft: "50px",
                }}
              >
                {" "}
                Add Transaction
              </h2>
            </div>
            {!props.isDataInserted &&
            Object.keys(column).length > 0 &&
            !isLoading ? (
              <Box
                sx={{
                  "& > :not(style)": { m: 3, width: "45ch", left: "20px" },
                }}
                noValidate
                autoComplete="off"
                className="Insert-data-box-contents"
              >
                {Object.entries(column.data).map(([cname, input], index) => {
                  const myInput = input.split("~");
                  if (input === "null") {
                    return (
                      <TextField
                        id="outlined-required"
                        label={cname}
                        name={cname}
                        key={index}
                        onFocus={(event) => handleFocus(event)}
                        onChange={handleSetJsonFieldsValues}
                        onClick={inputTouchHandler}
                      />
                    );
                  } else {
                    return (
              
                      //below logic is for selecting value from dropdown
                      <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 120 }}>
                        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-helper-label">{cname}</InputLabel>
                        <Select
                          labelId="demo-simple-select-helper-label"
                          id="demo-simple-select-helper"
                          label={cname}
                          displayEmpty
                          inputProps={{ "aria-label": "Without label" }}
                          onChange={(event) => handleDropdown(cname, event)}
                        >
                          {myInput.map((option) => (
                            <MenuItem key={option} value={option}>
                              {option}
                            </MenuItem>
                          ))}
                        </Select>
                      </FormControl>
                    );
                  }
                })}
                {errorMsg && !isTouched ? (
                  <p className="err-msg-insertRecordTab">{errorText}</p>
                ) : null}
              </Box>
            ) : (
              Spinner
            )}
            {colLength === 0 && (
              <p className="no-columns-present">No data to display.</p>
            )}
            <div className="button-textfield-section-insertRecordTab">
              <div className="button-createdby-container-insertRecordTab">
                <label className="created-by-label-insertRecordTab">
                  Created by :
                </label>
                <p className="created-by-textfield-section-insertRecordTab">
                  {userName}
                </p>
                <Button
                  onClick={handleChangeEvent}
                  className="custom-btn-insertRecordTab"
                  style={{
                    width: "70%",
                    backgroundColor: "rgb(25,133,242)",
                    marginTop: "10px",
                    marginBottom: "30px",
                  }}
                >
                  Add
                </Button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Card>
        </form>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
export default React.memo(InsertRecordTab);
```

How can I solve this issue where only 1 value is being selected from dropdown and not more than 1.